# Angular 12 with ERROR TypeError: this.handleError is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling, this

I am developing a web APP using Angular 12. I used a global error handler to process all my http errors. In my book portal component (in book module), When I called ReaderService
function (getFavorList) from another reader module, got an error: TypeError: this.handleError is not a function. If I call this function in same module is fine, and if I changed catchError code in getFavorList from

```
catchError(this.handleError('getFavorBookList'))
```

to

```
catchError((err)=>console.log(err))
```

This error will also disappeared, looks like "this" has problem, but I don't know how to fix without changing the error handling function. I also tried to bind(this) to this.handleError but not fixing the issue.

Following is code of book portal component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const bookID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    const readerName = this.tokenService.getUsername();
    this.commonService.setSubject(readerName);
    const readerID = this.readerAuthService.getReaderID();
    //Load book info from database
    this.bookService.getBook(bookID).subscribe((eBook: Book) => {
      if (eBook && eBook.bookTitle) {
        this.book = eBook;
        this.logger.info(`Success load profile of ${bookID}`)
      } else {
        this.logger.warn(`Failed to load ${bookID} profile from server`);
      }
      //Load the existing comments and display in page
      console.log('The comment length is ' + eBook.comments.length);
      const existComments = document.querySelector('div.existing-comments');
      if (eBook.comments.length > 0) {
        this.bookService.getBookComments(bookID).subscribe((comments: BookComment[]) => {
          if (comments && comments.length > 0) {
            this.logger.info(`Success load comments of book ${bookID}`)
            for (const item of comments) {
              let p1 = document.createElement('p');
              p1.className = 'comment-item';
              p1.innerHTML = item.comment;
              p1.style.fontSize = 'large';
              p1.style.fontFamily = 'Times New Roman';
              let p2 = document.createElement('p');
              p2.className = 'comment-item';
              p2.innerHTML = `---by ${item.readerName}`;
              p2.style.fontSize = 'large';
              p2.style.fontFamily = 'Times New Roman';
              existComments.appendChild(p1);
              existComments.appendChild(p2);
            }
          }
        });
      } else {
        let p1 = document.createElement('p');
        p1.className = 'comment-item';
        p1.innerHTML = 'Be the first person to write comments!';
        p1.style.fontSize = 'large';
        p1.style.fontFamily = 'Times New Roman';
        existComments.appendChild(p1);
      }
      this.commentForm.setValue({
        bookID: bookID,
        readerName: readerName,
        title: '',
        comment: '',
      });
    });
    //If book is in favor book list, disable add fovoriteBook button
    let favorInd = false;
    this.readerService.getFavorList(readerID).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data && data.length > 0) {
        for (const item of data) {
          if (item.bookID === bookID) {
            favorInd = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (favorInd) {
          const addFavorButton = document.querySelector('button.add-favorites') as HTMLButtonElement;
          addFavorButton.disabled = true;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Following is code of getFavorList:

```
private handleError: HandleError;

getFavorList(readerID): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`/api/reader/${readerID}/getfavourlist`).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('getFavorBookList')), shareReplay()
    )
  }
```

Following is code of hanleError part:

```
export type HandleError =
  <T> (operation?: string, result?: T) => (error: HttpErrorResponse) => Observable<T>;

/** Handles HttpClient errors */
@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorHandler {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private logger: NGXLogger,
  ) { }

  createHandleError = (serviceName = '') => {
    return <T>(operation = 'operation', result = {} as T) => this.handleError(serviceName, operation, result)
  }

  /**
   * Returns a function that handles Http operation failures.
   * This error handler lets the app continue to run as if no error occurred.
   * @param serviceName = name of the data service that attempted the operation
   * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
   * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
   */
  handleError<T>(serviceName = '', operation = 'operation', result = {} as T) {
    return (error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<T> => {
      //Generate error message
      let errorMessage = '';
      if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        errorMessage = `Client side error: ${error.error.message}`;
      } else if (error.status === 401) {
        errorMessage = `Server return ${error.status} with body "${error.error}"`;
        if (error.error.message.includes('Incorrect username or password')) {
          window.alert('Incorrect username or password, please check');
        } else {
          window.alert('Need login to access the contents.');
          if (serviceName.toLowerCase().indexOf('reader') != -1) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/reader/login');
          } else {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/librarian/login');
          }

        }
      } else {
        errorMessage = `Server return ${error.status} with body "${error.error}"`;
      }
      //Generate user friendly error log
      const errorLog = `HTTP Error in ${serviceName}: ${operation} failed: ${errorMessage}`;

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      this.logger.error(errorLog);

      return of(result);
    };
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could try ```catchError((err) => this.handleError('getFavorBookList')(err))```.
On the another hand it would be helpful to see how ```private handleError: HandleError;``` is being instantiated.

Comment: If you make console.log of this.handleError in getFavorList does it even exist there?

Comment: Lukasz, you solution works, thank you very much! Actually I thought about using arrow function to fix this, but I did not put (err) in the end...